# How to programmatically add menu for content type?

Tags: 7, routes, nodes

E.g. article has main menu as default, I want to add (and remove) second menu as available to article content type in my unit tests, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway I win with my lazyness and read Menu module source, you can add menu to available menus list of selected node like:

```
$type = 'article';
$curr_list = variable_get('menu_options_'.$type);
variable_set('menu_options_'.$type, array_merge($curr_list, array('new_menu')):
```

Comment: Neat, though is this more of a hack or is this the way you're supposed to do it?  I feel like going through the variable table isn't, err, "normal".

Comment: @LesterPeabody there is no another way probably, anyway it is only for my unit test, after that you can clean up all those things

Answer (score 0):

In hook_menu and set 'access callback' to custom function and then:

$node->type == 'my_node_type'

and/or user type that can access this node...

Comment: I meant add second menu on node edit form (available menu list)